# How to pass a json array to a global variable

Tags: javascript, json, promise, request, global-variables

I want to pass the resulting promis array to a global variable. How can I do this? Unfortunately, I didn't understand from the documentation how to do this, but in the browser I can pass to a global variable and access the values by key. Unfortunately, the option with "foo().then(json => console.log(json))" is not suitable, because there is no initialization of the array.
Thank you for any help! My code

```
async function foo(){
  var data = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/user'); 
  return data.json(); 
}

 let json = foo(); 
 console.log(json)
```

Comment: you can't - asynchrony can't be made synchronous

Comment: If you need to cache asynchronously acquired data then cache the promise, not the data itself, and access the data with either `await` or `.then()` wherever it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you assign a Promise object to you variable `json`

If you want to run asynchronous code, you need to pass a callback into the `.then()` method of Promise or wrap everything in `async` function and `await` for a result (see below).

```
async function foo(){
  var data = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/user'); 
  return data.json(); 
}

const global;

(async () => {
  const data = await foo();
  global = data;
  console.log('global', global)
})()
```